# Please center the toque in our logo inside the circle!

Tags: support, bug, design, logo

Not much else to say. I don't usually nitpick things like this but this is our site's logo and right now, it just looks a bit sloppy.

I respect all of the hard work the design team does but please, please fix this.

I know it's just a few pixels but when I reloaded the page to the updated site design, it was the very first thing that I saw. This exists in both the regular and meta version of the logo.

[image: Logo Currently]

OK, and one other thing... do we think the yellow is the "right" color here? It seems to be at odds with the rest of the page... as if it's **too** saturated. I can bring this up as a separate issue if you like.

For reference, here's the color from the chat room, which seems much more buttery:

[image: Chat room yellow]

Comment: Or put this content as an "answer" to the [site redesign question](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/2116/25286) as requested in that post.

Comment: I rather like the ketchup-red, mustard-yellow, and pickle-green motif, but perhaps everyone does not enjoy these condiments. Or it's happenstance.

Comment: By centered in this context, you mean you wish the hat was moved a few pixels to the left, right? Just clarifying.